# Remove multiple occurrences of a specific character inside a fixed pattern with a single Regex

Tags: regex, csv

First of all, I know how to solve this using two regex expressions but I was wondering if this can be done using just one.
Please see [this Regex101.com example](https://regex101.com/r/A4V6FE/2) for the following explanation.

Here's what I'm trying to do:
I am given a .csv file, of which one line looks like this:

> AAA,AAA,AAA,AAA,some text and a comma here, and there, test,,,,,,,,,,

The AAAs can be any length and any number/character. Those are the first four columns. The next part is

> some text and a comma here, and there, test

This string can contain zero or multiple commas. Let's consider this as the **fifth column**, although technically it isn't right now. The rest is just **always** 10 commas:

> ,,,,,,,,,,

The goal is to only **remove the commas inside the fifth column** and return the whole line back. So from this:

> AAA,AAA,AAA,AAA,some text and a comma here, and there, test,,,,,,,,,,

to this, notice the two removed commas:

> AAA,AAA,AAA,AAA,some text and a comma here and there test,,,,,,,,,,

Here's how I did it in two steps.
 First I get the fifth column using the first capture group with this regex:

```
(?:.*?,){4}(.*),{10}
```

Then I just use:

```
,
```

to match all commas and replace them with empty strings.

My guess is that you'd need to use lookahead and lookbehind and I tried a lot of variations but I was not able to find any solution.
Is there a way to achieve this in one single regex?
Thank you for reading.

Comment: Which language?

Comment: If you mean regex flavor then I just use the default one from regex101.com, which is PCRE (php) but if this is possible then I will probably use it in notepad++, which is boost regex. If I can't find a solution to do this in a single regex then I will parse this file through a small c# application.

Comment: Is this an XY Problem?  Is this whole task eliminated if you wrap that troublesome value (which contains commas) in double quotes before parsing the csv line?

Comment: https://3v4l.org/3Zge3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following regex will work for PCRE:

[See it in use here](https://regex101.com/r/A4V6FE/3)

```
(?:^(?:[^,]+,){4}|\G(?!\A))[^,]+\K,(?!,{9}$)
```

How it works:

- `(?:^(?:[^,]+,){4}|\G(?!\A))` match either of the following options

  - `^(?:[^,]+,){4}` starting from the beginning of the line, match any non-comma character one or more times, then `,`; match this series exactly 4 times
  - `\G(?!\A))` assert the position at the end of the previous match
- `[^,]+` match any character except `,` one or more times
- `\K` reset the starting point of the match; any previously consumed characters are no longer included in the final match
- `,` match this character literally
- `(?!,{9}$)` negative lookahead ensuring what follows is not 9 commas and the end of the line (this is to prevent the first of ten commas from being replaced)

---

Replace all won't work for every iteration of `,` in a line when completing this in Notepad++, but it'll still work. Just keep clicking *Replace All* until you see the message *Replace All: 0 occurrences were replaced*.